# Python, Методы и атрибуты

Tags: python, методы, атрибуты

Продолжаю изучать Python

Застрял на задачке: Реализовать копилку, пополняемую центами и долларами, начальная сумма в копилке 1 доллар и 1 цент

```
class PiggyBank:
def __init__(self, dollars, cents):
    self.dollars = dollars
    self.cents = cents

def add_money(self, deposit_dollars, deposit_cents):
    if deposit_cents + self.cents >= 100:
        self.cents = deposit_cents % 100
        self.dollars += deposit_cents // 100
    else:
        self.cents += deposit_cents
    return(self.dollars, self.cents)
```

Выводит:
Тестовый вход:
0 99
Правильный выход:
2 0

Вывод вашего кода:
1 99

Не могу найти ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно немного упростить Ваш код:

```
class PiggyBank:
    def __init__(self, dollars, cents):
        self.dollars = dollars
        self.cents = cents

    def add_money(self, deposit_dollars, deposit_cents):
        self.dollars += deposit_dollars + (self.cents + deposit_cents) // 100
        self.cents = (self.cents + deposit_cents) % 100
        return(self.dollars, self.cents)

bank = PiggyBank(1, 1)
bank.add_money(0, 99)
print(bank.__dict__)  # {'dollars': 2, 'cents': 0}
bank.add_money(1, 0)
print(bank.__dict__)  # {'dollars': 3, 'cents': 0}
bank.add_money(1, 1)
print(bank.__dict__)  # {'dollars': 4, 'cents': 1}
```

Ваш же код нужно доработать учетом долларов и правильным пересчетом центов:

```
def add_money(self, deposit_dollars, deposit_cents):
    if deposit_cents + self.cents >= 100:
        self.dollars += deposit_dollars + (deposit_cents + self.cents) // 100
        self.cents = (deposit_cents + self.cents) % 100
    else:
        self.cents += deposit_cents
        self.dollars += deposit_dollars
    return(self.dollars, self.cents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
class PiggyBank:
    def __init__(self, dollars, cents):
        self.dollars = dollars
        self.cents = cents

    def add_money(self, deposit_dollars, deposit_cents):
        _cents = deposit_cents + self.cents
        print(f'deposit_dollars={deposit_dollars}, '
              f'deposit_cents={deposit_cents}, _cents={_cents}')   #
        if _cents >= 100:
#            self.cents = deposit_cents % 100
            self.cents = _cents % 100                              # +++
#            self.dollars += deposit_cents // 100
            self.dollars += deposit_dollars + (_cents // 100)       # +++
        else:
            self.cents += deposit_cents
            self.dollars += deposit_dollars                        # +++
        return self.dollars, self.cents
    

piggyBank = PiggyBank(1, 99)   
print(f'${piggyBank.dollars},{piggyBank.cents}')

print(piggyBank.add_money(2, 5))
print(f'${piggyBank.dollars},{piggyBank.cents}')

print(piggyBank.add_money(1, 0))
print(f'${piggyBank.dollars},{piggyBank.cents}') 

print(piggyBank.add_money(3, 3))
print(f'${piggyBank.dollars},{piggyBank.cents}')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за помощь и советы!!!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, правильнее с точки зрения чистоты кода добавить метод для конвертации валют и вызывать его при добавлении. Так же можно было бы проперти атрибут результата сделать и вызывать его там.

```
class PiggyBank:
    def __init__(self, dollars=1, cents=1):
        self.dollars = dollars
        self.cents = cents

    def add_money(self, deposit_dollars=0, deposit_cents=0):
        self.dollars += deposit_dollars
        self.cents += deposit_cents
        self.conversion()

    def conversion(self):
        if self.cents >= 100:
            count_dollars = self.cents // 100
            self.cents -= count_dollars*100
            self.dollars += count_dollars

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.dollars} dollars {self.cents} cents'


bank = PiggyBank()
bank.add_money(0, 99)
print(bank) # выход: 2 dollars 0 cents
```

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того, что вот так, напрямую лазить в объект -  не очень хорошо, можно написать еще короче и экономнее. Хотя, конечно, на вкус и цвет..

```
class PiggyBank:
    def __init__(self, dollars, cents):
        self.accumulation = dollars+cents*0.01

    def add_money(self, deposit_dollars, deposit_cents):
        self.accumulation += deposit_dollars
        self.accumulation += deposit_cents*0.01
        return()
    
    def how_rich_i_am(self):
        print (f"{int(self.accumulation//1)} dollars {int(self.accumulation%1*100)} cents.")
        return()
```

Имеем:

```
bank = PiggyBank(1, 1)
bank.how_rich_i_am()
bank.add_money(0, 99)
bank.how_rich_i_am()
```

Получаем:

```
1 dollars 1 cents.
2 dollars 0 cents.
```